# What is the probability of getting at least 2 white balls?

Tags: probability

A bowl contain 3 balls, 2 white and 1 black. We pick one ball and put it back 3 times. What are the odds of getting at least 2 white balls?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Drawing with replacement makes the count of white balls in three draws a Binomial distribution: $$W\sim\mathcal{Bin}(3, \tfrac 1 3)$$

Now find $\mathsf P(W\geq 2)$

Comment: so that gives me (3*(2/3)(2/3)(1/3))+(1*(2/3)^3)= 0.74074, am i correct here?

Comment: @spexel Yes, to five decimal places.